# Make only certain parts of the header transition

Tags: html, css

I want to make only certain parts of the header transition, however currently everything transitions which I don't want it to, specifically the "slides". I Have tried putting the slides into a separate div and placing it on top however I could not get it to appear even when using Z-index.

Relevant code:

CSS:

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 108px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
<h1 id=>NZ Great Walks</h1> <div id="NHide">   
<ul>
    <li><a href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide2" title="Sample Text">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide1" title="Sample Text">Slide 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</header>
```

Here is a Jsfiddle (sorry for very poor structure)

http://jsfiddle.net/pddmq95v/

Comment: Don't add a transition to the whole header tag. Instead, target it to a more specific part of the header contents. For example, if you only wanted that h1 tag to transition, use `header h1{}` as your selector instead